# Separated process and GUI -- how to start the application in the correct way

Tags: linux, user-interface, process, tcl

I have a separate process and GUI for my application. Details below. Now I am ready to bring the application "in production". Although there are likely only 2 users on this planet I want to handle the startup of the application correctly. That is, adhering to the correct Unix philosophy. Although the application might be able to run in Windows, I am not interested.

I think I have 2 options:

- Starting both the player process and the GUI from their own init.d scripts. And have a third script to call both. Usually placed in an autostart directory. Or just have both the process and the gui startup script in the correct rcX.d
- Start the player process from an init.d script and fork the GUI from within the process. I could pass parameters to the process to tell whether or not it should start the GUI. This does not preclude starting a GUI process manually elsewhere.

Both options have variations, but the difference between the two is fundamental.

**More info on the application**

The application is an internet radio player. But with the special feature it can play back previously recorded streams, introducing a time shift to compensate for time differences if the player and transmitter are in different time zones.
The recorder is part of the same project, but not part of the application.

The application consists of the player which is able to play headless, and fully controlled through configuration files. The player can also be controlled by a GUI which communicates with the player through TCP/IP. The application gracefully handles if the player runs without GUI a single GUI, or with multiple GUI's. The GUI gracefully handles the absence or re-connection of the player.

If the player runs headless I want to connect from any PC with a GUI. In some situations I want to use the application and GUI on the same laptop or PC. The main application is a dedicated RasPI player with touch screen. This RasPI should launch  both the player and GUI simultaneously when I start the application. Optionally I can start another GUI from another PC to control settings I cannot access thru the touch screen.

I don't think it is relevant, but both parts are written in Tcl/Tk. The player has an extension which interfaces to the libmpv API, part of the mpv media player.

So the player and the GUI are so far independent nothing breaks if one runs without the other, and recover gracefully when they both run. The question is how to start both processes. Independent init.d scripts or forking.

Comment: GUI processes (or anything that touches user-facing devices, so the sound player would also be this) typically need to be started within the context of a GUI session, not directly from the init system. The stuff in rcX.d would, I imagine, be a stream recorder so that streams can be recorded even when the system is unattended.

Comment: The stream recorder is not part of the application. It does not have a GUI. As for the player, as I understand it, you mean to start the GUI and then start the player from the GUI? That doesn't seem to right. The GUI can run on a different host and would not be able to start a player process.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the player and the GUI are implemented as Tcl scripts, you can use the `source` command to load one from the other. For example, when starting the GUI, it can detect that the player is not running (because the socket connection fails). In that case it can do `source player.tcl`. To avoid name conflicts you can use different namespaces, or load the player in a separate interpreter. I don't expect either of the components to do any blocking actions. But if they do, you can even load the player in an interpreter in another thread.

```
set dir [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]
interp create player
player eval [list source [file join $dir player.tcl]]
```

There are other possibilities for deciding between starting one or both components, like passing a command line option to either of the components to also load the other component.

---

Since you are specifically interested in linux, another strategy would be to make use of [dbus](https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/dbus). Your player could publish a dbus interface (using [dbif](https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/dbif)). The GUI can then call a method of that interface, with the "-autostart" option on (the default). When set up correctly, that would cause the player to start, if it isn't already running.

In player.tcl:

```
package require dbif
dbif connect tk.tcl.mpvplayer
dbif method / Version {} version {return $::version}
```

You can add more methods, and signals and properties. But since you already have a TCP/IP interface, you don't need to implement a full API via dbus.

In your GUI application:

```
package require dbus
dbus connect
# Auto-start the player, if necessary
dbus call -dest tk.tcl.mpvplayer / tk.tcl.mpvplayer Version
```

To enable auto-starting the player, create a file `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/tk.tcl.mpvplayer.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=tk.tcl.mpvplayer
Exec=/home/pi/mpvplayer/player.tcl
```

The examples above use the session bus, which is normally associated with the display (:0). To make it work when the player runs headless, you may need to set the DISPLAY variable for it to connect to the correct session bus. Alternatively you can use the system bus. But that will require some adjustments.

Comment: The problem is not so much how to start one application from the other. The question is, should I start the GUI from the player, or should I start the player independently. Also taking into account the player might run headless, the player might run on the same host, or the GUI might run on a different host. If the GUI runs on a different host, starting the player from the GUI seems not a viable option.

Comment: For now I have settled to start the GUI from the player. I can pass the --no-gui option to the player if ir runs headless. Most important reason for settling to start the GUI from the player is that it is convenient to pass command line parameters to the GUI, like the player's IP address/port and the other configuration which is specific to that player instance.